Is it true that $\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac{1}{b+1}+\frac{1}{c+1}+\frac{1}{d+1}\geqslant 2$ for positive $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ with $abcd=1$?

If $a,b,c,d>0$, and $abcd=1$, is the following true?
$$\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac{1}{b+1}+\frac{1}{c+1}+\frac{1}{d+1}\geqslant 2$$

My attempt: I have a 'intuitive' feeling that it holds for $a=b=c=d=1$ since if anyone deviates from this the $1/x$ will grow quite large. This actually popped up into the solution of a olympiad problem and I wanted to know how this could be proved.

What have you tried?

I tried clearing denominators and am gm but it didnt really work

Can you add the source of the olympiad question? :-)

@calculatormathematical Let a,b,c,d be positive real numbers such that $abcd$=1. Prove that $\sum_{cyclic} \frac{1+ab}{1+a}>=4.(Romania,2003)$

Sanity check: What happens if you make $a, b, c$ large and $d$ therefore very small?

@MarkBennet it appears that I was sleep deprived at the time

The inequality is false in general. Consider $(a,b,c,d)=\left(x,x,x,\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$ where $x$ tends to infinity. Then the lefthandside tends to $1$ which is smaller than $2$.

Right thanks,I proved it falsely it seems
